# Counts number of rows with like in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database. I want to count number of rows where the id starts from 1112 . 
(id is string and its format in data base is `nchar(7)`)

I have 20 rows that start from 1112 like `1112000`, `1112001`, `1112002`,....

But when I write this query returns 0!.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
FROM table
WHERE (id LIKE '1112*')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `%` instead of `*`.

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS num
FROM           table
WHERE        (id LIKE '1112%')
```

[LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try `%` instead of `*`

```
"id LIKE '1112%')
```